# Javascript object get value above

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
    var structure = {
    "root":{
        "name":"Main Level",
        nodes:{
            "node1":{
                "label":"Node 1"  
            },
            "node2":{
                "label":"Node 2",
                "selected": true
            },
            "node3":{
                "label":"Node 3"  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In javascript how do I search the object for 'selected: true', and get the label value above it, i.e "Node 2"

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a for loop.

```
var nodes = structure.roots.nodes;
var nodeYouWant;
for (var obj in nodes){
   if (nodes[obj].selected == true){
      nodeYouWant = obj;  // Now "node2"
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to test `nodes[obj].selected`, not `obj.selected`.

Comment: There's also no need for the `== true` part. Just `if (nodes[obj].selected){...` is enough.

Comment: Also, you should really be adding a `hasOwnProperty` check so that extensions to `Object.prototype` don't show up in the loop later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the keys of the `structure.root.nodes` (which you can get with `Object.keys`) and check whether the node object at that key is `selected`. For the purposes of this demo, I just logged the selected `node.label`.

```js
var structure = {
  "root": {
    "name": "Main Level",
    nodes: {
      "node1": {
        "label": "Node 1"
      },
      "node2": {
        "label": "Node 2",
        "selected": true
      },
      "node3": {
        "label": "Node 3"
      }
    }
  }
}

var nodes = structure.root.nodes,
    keys = Object.keys(nodes)

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var node = nodes[keys[i]]
  if (node.selected) {
    console.log("Selected:", node.label)
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (n in structure.root.nodes) {
  if (structure.root.nodes[n].selected) {
    console.log("the node which is selected is: " + n); 
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for `hasOwnProperty` when dealing with object literals.

Answer (score 0):

This will recursively traverse your object looking for the selected value, returning the key name if found.

```js
const structure = {
  "root": {
    "name": "Main Level",
    nodes: {
      "node1": {
        "label": "Node 1"
      },
      "node2": {
        "label": "Node 2",
        "selected": true
      },
      "node3": {
        "label": "Node 3"
      }
    }
  }
}

const findSelected = (obj, ret = '') => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].selected) {
      return key
    }
    if (obj[key].constructor === Object) {
      ret = findSelected(obj[key])
      if (ret) return ret
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  findSelected(structure) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the way below.

```
var structure = {
    "root": {
        "name": "Main Level",
        nodes: {
            "node1": {
                "label": "Node 1"
            },
            "node2": {
                "label": "Node 2",
                "selected": true
            },
            "node3": {
                "label": "Node 3"
            }
        }
    }
};
let nodes = structure.root.nodes;
Object.keys(nodes).forEach(key => {
    if(nodes[key].selected === true){
        //do something like below
        //console.log(nodes[key].label);
    }
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys